# Not getting what I want using the format function

Tags: python, csv

Ok. I have a CSV, and I'm trying to use the format function to rearrange the order in which the data of the columns prints.

In other words, how can I use the format function to print columns in the order e,d,c instead of the default c,d,e?

Here's what I have so far:

```
for row in books:


    print [item.upper() for item in row]

    print [format(item[])
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the builtin [`format`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format)? Are you aware what it does? It's not at all what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the order of the columns, you can do:

```
for row in books:
    print list(reversed(row))  # Prints the reversed row, as a list
    print ', '.join(reversed(row))  # Prints a single string of comma-separated values
    print [row[index] for index in (2, 0, 1)]  # General order change
    print ', '.join(row[index] for index in (2, 0, 1))  # Same thing, but prints a string
```

Answer (score 2):

### Formatting strings

I am not sure what are you asking for, but this may suit your needs:

```
>>> my_items = ['c', 'd', 'e']
>>> print '{2} {1} {0}'.format(*my_items)
e d c
```

It uses formatting, which allows you to print items in **any order you like**. See [documentation of `format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format) for more.

### Reversing lists

If you want just to **reverse order of the array**, just provide `-1` for "step" part within brackets after list's name:

```
>>> my_items = ['c', 'd', 'e']
>>> my_items[::-1]
['e', 'd', 'c']
```

so your code may look like this:

```
for row in books:
    print [item.upper() for item in row[::-1]]
```

which will print list of uppercase items in a row, but in reversed order.

Comment: Thanks Tadeck. So by assigning the c,d,e values(?) inside the brackets, Python knows that they represent columns in the CSV?

Comment: @mantissa45: If you convert the CSV line into list, then you can refer to them by indexes like `{0}` and `{1}` in `'{0} {1}'.format(*row)`, but if you convert the line into a dictionary eg. `{'cola':'a','colb':'b'}`, then by unpacking it you can refer to them by their names like that: `'{cola} {colb}'.format(**row)`. It just depends, what exactly your `row` variable is.

Comment: @mantissa45: If you use [`csv.reader()`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader), then your row is probably suitable for the first case I mentioned in my previous comment - `'{0} {1}'.format(*row)` - and yes, the number within curly brackets is the index of the column (starting with `0` for the 1st column).

Comment: @mantissa45: You are welcome. Just let me know about the results.

Comment: @mantissa: Ok. So I tried the first suggestion you made, and it worked just as it did in your code sample. However, this seems to only rearrange the name of the columns themselves, and not their content. In other words, I can print e,d,c or c,e,d etc., but what I want is to apply this formating to the content in all the rows under these columns. Does this make sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5361/discussion-between-mantissa45-and-tadeck)

Answer (score 1):

Isolating the column order from the input data is a good use for `DictWriter`.

```
>>> data = [range(i, i+3) for i in range(5)]
>>> import csv, StringIO
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO()
```

Create the writer, with fields in the order you need.

```
>>> writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ('e', 'd', 'c'))
```

And create some way to make a dict that has those keys, from whatever your input is.

```
>>> def datamap(row):
...     return dict(zip('cde', row))
...
```

Then it's just a matter of using the csv writer as normal. (`writeheader()` is just a convenience so we can see what the columns look like, it is by no means mandatory)

```
>>> writer.writeheader()
>>> for datum in data:
...     writer.writerow(datamap(datum))
...

>>> print f.getvalue()
e,d,c
2,1,0
3,2,1
4,3,2
5,4,3
6,5,4

>>>
```